# Search across multiple controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, solr

So I'm working on a Rails project in which I have a frontend interacting with multiple controllers to retrieve information. I have `instructors` and `courses` controllers and I am trying to implement a search feature where I can select which controller to search from using a drop down box, and when I click the search button, it will only search the selected controller.

My search box on the home page looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7yzk.png (SO won't let me embed an image)

The code to make it is below:

```
      <%= form_tag(params[:option], :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
      <%= select(:option,options_for_select([['Instructors', 'instructors'], ['Courses', 'courses'],['Departments','departments']])) %>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
      <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, html: {class: "button button-red"}%>
      <% end %>
```

*Special note on line 1 where I use `params[:option]`, this populates with the information from the 'option' field, so if I select 'Instructors', the option becomes `instructors`.*

**Problem**: On the homepage when I enter a name and  click search the url that is created is as follows:

`http://0.0.0.0:3000/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&option=%2Finstructors&search=John`

and it takes me right back to the homepage. I can see in the debug information, that it isn't even getting to the right controller, it's only looking at the static pages controller.

If I click the search button again it brings me to the correct page with the correct search results:

`http://0.0.0.0:3000/instructors?utf8=%E2%9C%93&option=%2Finstructors&search=john`

I'm using Solr to do the searching, and I have everything working properly except this pathing issue which requires multiple clicks. My controller code for `instructors` index looks like this:

```
def index
    if params[:search] != ''
        @search = Instructor.search do
            fulltext params[:search]
        end
        @instructors = @search.results

    else 
        @instructors = Instructor.all
    end
end
```

I feel like I am making an architectural mistake somewhere, and any input would be appreciated.

Comment: In your log, what controller is that initial search-form getting submitted to (who yields the search form in the first place)? That's where you check the submitted params to see which model to search, and redirect to the appropriate controller (instructor or course) with the params from the search-form.

Comment: @railsdog: `Started GET "/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&option=%2Finstructors&search=george" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-26 21:25:52 -0700
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I feel like I am making an architectural mistake somewhere, and any input would be appreciated.

Exactly right. The mistake is this: `params[:option]` is a serverside value. In order to get to the server, you are creating a request using the form submission. The form decides where to submit using the serverside `params[:option]`. It's like trying to pull yourself by your own bootstraps.

In more detail, what happens is this:

- The serverside receives the request for your `/`
- The serverside renders your form. The form's action is set to `params[:option]`, but such an option is not set. The default value for a form action when it is not specified is the same page you're on.
- The clientside displays the form. The user selects *Instructors* and submits the form.
- The clientside contacts the form's action (i.e. the same page), and transfers the form's values (`option` and `search`)
- The serverside `/` receives the request, and renders the form
- This time, `params[:option]` is set to `instructors`
- The client submits the form again; this time, the form has a correctly set `action` (the received `params[:option]` from the last cycle)

Two easy approaches to solve this would be:

- Use JavaScript to dynamically modify the form's `action` attribute as the `option` is selected
- Make a dedicated search controller/action that will handle search for both kinds, depending on the value of `params[:option]`
- Make another action at serverside that will redirect your request to one of the other two actions, depending on the value of `params[:option]`